# How to load an external URL at inApp browser on Worklight?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Im using this code to load an external URL, but it only shows a blank page

```
window.open(result.invocationResult.data , '_blank');
```

`result.invocationResult.data` is fetching the URL correctly and it works on PC browsers, it fails on Android 4.4, I also test that app on a mobile browser and it works and fail inside the mobile app.

here is my catlog:

```
07-10 12:53:13.890: D/InAppBrowser(1204): target = _blank
07-10 12:53:13.890: D/InAppBrowser(1204): in blank
07-10 12:53:14.880: I/Choreographer(1204): Skipped 134 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
07-10 12:53:14.920: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:15.900: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:15.950: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:15.990: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:16.000: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:16.050: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:16.080: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:16.110: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:16.140: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:16.190: W/AwContents(1204): nativeOnDraw failed; clearing to background color.
07-10 12:53:16.280: D/CordovaLog(1204): data:text/html,chromewebdata: Line 12 : Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png
07-10 12:53:16.290: I/chromium(1204): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)
07-10 12:53:16.360: D/CordovaWebViewClient(1204): onPageFinished(file:///data/data/com.test/files/www/default/index.html#&ui-state=dialog)
07-10 12:53:16.370: D/CordovaActivity(1204): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///data/data/com.test/files/www/default/index.html#&ui-state=dialog)
07-10 12:53:16.720: I/chromium(1204): [INFO:CONSOLE(12)] "Not allowed to load local resource: file:///android_asset/webkit/android-weberror.png", source: data:text/html,chromewebdata (12)
07-10 12:53:17.010: I/Choreographer(1204): Skipped 52 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
```

my URL is :

```
  myUrl = 'https://10.0.177.119:9444/teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=108355&zResetContext=true';
```

it has an https cert created on openssl.
platform version

```
platformVersion="6.1.0.00.20131219-1900"
```

and android version:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

Comment: can you give the url that you are trying to load ?

Comment: Also mention your Worklight version.

Comment: I have edited my question, I guess that could be a problem with Worklight or android security, at mobile app it tries to load an error page but it works perfectly on any other browser.

Answer (score 0):

In my main.js I've used `window.open("http://www.apache.org", "_blank);` and launched the app in the Android Emulator (Android 4.4.2).

It opened successfully.

Try as well using a 'regular' URL such as the above; see if it opens.
If it opens and yours not, perhaps the issue is somewhere there.

Notes:

1. You say it fails, but you do not describe how it fails (what is happening?)
2. You are using 6.1.0.00; I suggest that you will upgrade to the latest 6.1 (6.1.0.01) release by download the latest version from IBM Fix Central.

Answer (score 0):

Even I had the same error today and searching for the solution. I found that the mistake made by me was very silly. I forgot to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` in the manifest file.
I know this is very late to answer this question. But I hope this answer might help someone who is searching solution with the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

the problem is related to AuthRealm or https cert, I have an AuthRealm to accesing services from BPM Process Center and if i change the URL like this I can avoid that error:

```
myUrl = 'http://ectest556ws1:9081/teamworks/process.lsw?zWorkflowState=1&zTaskId=108355';
```

Comment: Please update your original question or ask in new one instead of posting as an answer. My guess here is that you don't have a valid ssl certificate against your server, and the chrome browser being loaded will not allow that url to be used.